# Why am I able to use django template variables dynamically?

Tags: javascript, python, django

My understanding of drango templates is that everything happens on server side and then it generates an html out of the templates. After, generation, it is just plain text in the html. But for some reason, I am able to use django variables dynamically in javascript.

Here is a javascript example:

```
$("#smth").append("<li>{{djangoObject.0.id}}</li>");
```

Even if I put this in an event handler, meaning, it for sure will be called after the html generation, it works just fine.

How and most importantly, WHY does django keep the variable in the client-side?

Comment: Django templates also runs in serverside, your code runs in server side. {{djangoObject.0.id}} is not a client side variable. No one calls it "template" if its not dynamic

Comment: Hint: right click on your page, and ask to see the source code - then search for the above javascript snippet.

Comment: @jsbueno Thanks, I got it already. My brain had a blackout, because of long day before I was writing this question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not being used client side, it's just being rendered directly into the Javascript string. So if `djangoObject[0].id` were 12, for example, the resulting code would look like

```
$("#smth").append("<li>12</li>");
```

Which, obviously, would run just fine. It's not dynamic though, and be sure to keep that in mind - it doesn't fetch `id` at the point of the event happening. It fetches it at template rendering, which happens before the HTML (and embedded Javascript) is sent to the client (your browser).

Comment: I will accept this for your reputation, thanks for taking your time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

This code rendered to something like `$("#smth").append("<li>123</li>");`.  Of course this work without any problem after the html generation.

Comment: How is it "rendered"? If it happens AFTER rendering the initial html, how does it render once more?